# function import in entity framework error

Tags: entity-framework

hi i have an error in the entity framework. i imported the sp get() into EF and return results as complex datatype 'GetResult'.In the edmx xml i have set the 'Amount' type to decimal.

```
<ComplexType Name="Get_Result">
          <Property Type="String" Name="Description" Nullable="true" MaxLength="255" />
          <Property Type="Decimal" Name="Amount" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Type="Decimal" Name="Gst" Nullable="false" Precision="19" />
          <Property Type="Decimal" Name="Total" Nullable="true" Precision="19" />
        </ComplexType>
```

I try to bind the result with datagridview

```
gridview.DataSource = db.Get().ToList();
```

it kept giving me error message like this. and i couldn't find int32 anywhere in EF and have updated & built the EF multiple times.

```
The 'Amount' property on 'Get_Result' could not be set to a 'Int32' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'Decimal'.
```

any help appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved the issue by handling null exception